# Nested maps in Qt's QCborStreamWriter?

Tags: qt, serialization, qt5, cbor, nested-map

My program provides a large amount of data, organized in **nested maps**, that I would like to serialize and write in a file. Originally, I used a **QJsonDocument** with **QJsonMap**'s and **QJsonArray**'s, but the file writing process at the end is very long and the file too large (>400MB). So I looked into **QCborStreamWriter** but I can't find examples with nested maps.

Is there a way to do it ?
**QCborStreamWriter::append()** does not take a **QCborMap** as argument.

```
QCborStreamWriter writer;
writer.startArray();
QCBorMap map;
writer.append(map); <= not accepted
writer.endArray();
```

Comment: ["To create arrays and maps, QCborStreamWriter provides startArray() and startMap() overloads, which must be terminated by the corresponding endArray() and endMap() functions."](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcborstreamwriter.html#details)

Answer (score 0):

Calling repeatedly startMap() and endMap() seems to do the trick.

```
QCborStreamWriter writer(&file);
writer.startMap();
writer.append("A");
writer.append(1);
writer.append("B");
writer.append(2);
writer.append("C");
writer.startMap(); // start nested map
writer.append("C1");
writer.append(3.1);
writer.append("C2");
writer.append(3.2);
writer.append("C3");
writer.append(3.3);
writer.endMap(); // end nested map
writer.endMap();
```

and produces the following tree:

```
{
"A": 1,
"B": 2,
"C": {
  "C1": 3.1,
  "C2": 3.2,
  "C3": 3.3
},
"D": 4
}
```